# Can you import .CSV data into SQL Server using commands from Powershell 3 or 4?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Is there a Powershell script for PowerShell version 3 or version 4 that allows you to import values from a .CSV file into a SQL table?

1. I'm trying to figure out whether I can script a PowerShell job to import data, using enterprise Servers running older versions of PowerShell (It would be preferred if this can be done without importing any additional modules)
2. (Nice to have, but not necessary) Also interested to know if there's a way to report the success or failure of that job, to a log file?

This is the script I've tested in PowerShell 5, just can't use this on my older servers:

```
$database = 'DATABASE';
$server = 'SERVER';
$table = 'TABLE';
$MyData = import-csv \\TESTPATH\licenses_v2.csv -delimiter '|' | 
select-object FirstName,LastName,Department,Title;
Write-DbaDataTable -sqlinstance $server -database $database -table $table -inputobject $MyData -KeepNulls;
```

Comment: You can use that script on Powershell 3/4, you just have to install the `dbatools` module in a different way. Any method but #1 [in the install instructions](https://dbatools.io/download/) should work fine. You *can* do it without the module, but you'll be reinventing the wheel and I'm sure that the module has been more thoroughly tested than your version will be.

Comment: Would you happen to know of a method i can use to report the failure or success?

Comment: If the function returns an error, it failed. If it returns nothing, it's successful.

Comment: I mean is there a way to export the status of the 'job' whether successful or unsuccessful to a txt file, to keep a record of an automated step in a SSIS package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, I just need to install the DBATools module.